# prevent render.com server from sleeping using python

Tags: python, cron

I got an app hosted on a render server, and as it's under the free tier, it sleeps after 15m of inactivity. i've tried uptimerobot and cron by setting up HTTP calls but can't seem to keep the program alive. Is there any way to keep my render app awake?